# Need help in capturing an image using html5

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, camera

I am trying to make a simple camera app for a mobile device using html5. I used the following approaches, for capturing an image using html5, but none of them worked. Firstly, I tried to use get getUserMedia function of the navigator obj, but it wasnt supported on my latest version of chrome on an android tablet. Secondly I trying to use phoneGap. I downloaded the js phonegap file from the code.google, but whenever I ran navigator.camera.getPicture(); function, with phonegap.js imported, I ran with the following error, "cannot call getPicture of undefined". Do you have any solutions or suggestion for me to make this simple app. Thanks in advance. Here is a small sample code which I had used for debugging, which wasnt working.
P.S. I dont think I should be using a jquery plugin, as my research told me that it used a small component of flash, which again may not be there on all browsers.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<body>
<script>    navigator.camera.getPicture();   </script>
<script src="phonegap-1.0.0.js"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't you need to include the JS library before you try to use it?

Comment: omg people still use phone gap 1.0.0 :O

Comment: I wanted to an API for accessing the camera, and this is the first I got when I googled for one, do you know any others which I can use?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that navigator.camera is specified anywhere in W3C specs. 
That kind of device is out of HTML5 domain.

Just in case, at least on iOS6 this element:

```
<input type=file>
```

placed inside submitable form will allow you to make camera shot and send it to the server.